# Prevent Multi-login cause an error and prevent log in again

Tags: asp.net, session, session-timeout

In the currently project I am working on it , we decide to prevent multi-login 
For doing this , I insert a record in a sql table when any user log in to website , an delete its record when log out (I use the session_end method for doing this)

Here is a problem : I set the sessions timeout on 10 minutes , so by using this strategy , when a user close the browser for log in again , he must wait from 1 to 10 minutes(because there is a record in sql table that will delete by session_end method in maximum 10 minute future and prevent user to login again).

Is there any body out there to help me in this issue ?every idea can be usefull

Sorry about my bad syntax, I am new in English. For more details comment me please

Regards ,
Ali Foroughi

Comment: I think you can do it in one way. Whenever user closes the browser window you can pop up a message and ask the user that by closing this window you will be sign out from the site. see this post http://forums.asp.net/p/1205886/2121753.aspx seems little difficult

Comment: It does not sound like a very reliable solution. What if (for instance) a power outage takes down the server. Session end events will not run, leaving users locked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use the session timeout to prevent multiple login for the reason the you state that a user must wait 10 minutes to login again if he close his browser by accident, the browser crash or like a comment, a problem with the server and the connection record stay in the database. There is also the possibility that some else change the Session time setting without your knowledge to 1 minute or 1 hours.

I participate in a system some year ago that add the requirement of having only on connection per user. We designed the system that consider the last login to be the valid one. We also decided not to use Session timeout to check if the connection is still active. Each time the user did an action on the website, we check the last time he did an action with a value store in the database and compare it the current time. If the difference was under the maximum inactivity value (like 10 minutes), the system updated the value to the current time and allow to continue or redirected to the timeout page.
With this solution, it prevented the multiple login and also prevented many problem to occurs and the user didn't have to wait to reconnect to the website.